# JSP: Display Loading Image While Page Loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have these code in my JSP to Display a Loading Image While Page Loads:

```
  <style type="text/css">
                .loader {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
                background: url('${contextPath}/images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
                }
            </style> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>

<div class="loader"></div>
```

and it is working fine. Now I want to show the same image after clicking a link with these code

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click( function(e) {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        } )
    });
</script>
```

But Its not working at all

Comment: Are you saying you want a transition between pages? Because that's impossible. You can get kind of close, otherwise to do this you'd have to make it a single-page app. Which is very complex especially if you don't wanna recode your whole project.

Comment: $(".loader").fadeIn("slow") instead of fadeOut

Comment: @Araz, please transform to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click( function(e) {
        $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
        } )
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert('hiding loader and showing body')
      $('.loader').hide();
      $('.body').show();
});
```

```css
.loader {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: red;
}
.body{
  background:#DDD;  
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
<div class="body">After load</div>
```